# My theme isn't being Responsive

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

I'm working on a [site](http://www.fit2workcorporatewellness.com). It's based off the [Fit WordPress theme](http://themeforest.net/item/fit-fitnessgym-responsive-wordpress-theme/3407694).

The theme is responsive and as far as i can tell they put in all the meta tags and such but I can't get it to work. It's stretching images and menus are missing and I keep changing my CSS but to no avail. It doesn't look good on phones and even when I resize my window things are shifting around (other issue).

Comment: Rodney, I've edited your Question just to remove everything unrelated to the real issue. As you can see, a giant block of text can be shortened to the essentials. Salutations, ranting, "help" and thanks are considered noise. Check this little guide: [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your theme is responsive.  I have checked out your website at all screen resolutions, font sizes, etc. ...

Most likely, your theme uses [@media queries](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/responsive-layouts-using-css-media-queries/) in the stylesheet to achieve this effect, although there are other ways.

That's the difference between **responsive** and **fluid**; I think you're conflating the two ideas.  A responsive design will switch things around based on screen resolutions (may put your sidebar at the bottom, menu elsewhere, etc.) ...

The main difference is that Fluid Layouts (also called Liquid Layouts) are based on proportionally laying out your website so elements take up the same percent of space on different screen sizes, while Responsive Design uses CSS Media Queries to present different layouts based on screen sizes/type of screen. For some examples of both kinds of design, see [Inspiration: Fluid & Responsive Design](http://webdesignerwall.com/trends/inspiration-fluid-responsive-design).

Fluid's intent is to keep the same spatial weighting to all elements, and works okay on different sizes of screens of the same sort. They tend to look okay on a 32", high resolution monitor and a 12" lower resolution laptop. They're pretty easy to implement.

Responsive design's intent is to serve different devices layouts tailored specifically for the type of screen. Your site's layout will generally be cut down to a single column on a smartphone for example.

For a deeper look, check out [Fixed vs. Fluid vs. Elastic Layout: What’s The Right One For You](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/)? by Smashing Magazine, which goes in depth on the primary changes in Fluid design. They also have [Responsive Web Design Guidelines and Tutorials](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/) for an overview of responsive (with plenty of links should you want to dig deeper into Responsive Design).

Responsive Design is very much "in" at the moment thanks to Mobile, Smashing actually has a [whole tag for responsive design](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/tag/responsive-design/).

On a personal note, my opinion is that your site is just fine how it is.  I prefer responsive layouts.

Comment: Thank you very much Jason. That does make sense since I originally did learn a bit about Fluid design but didn't really get a chance to implement it. I'm just unhappy with the way it looks on my cell phone (since I lose my menus on the home page and images on other pages are stretched and crushed to fit the screen size) I would like it to resemble my desktop size which I believe would mean that I would need to make it a fluid design. Your answer definitely helps to clarify what I'm doing wrong so thanks again.

Comment: No problem.  The way your theme is set up, on my Android, you have to click "Menu" to get your menu to appear ... just above the search function.  So you're not losing your menu; you just have to understand your theme's responsive design.